# If someone resigns from a firm while their patent application is under processing, will their name be used in patent application

Tags: patents

I couldn't find any law/rule stating that if a person resigns from a company after the company have filed for an patent by that person, whether his/her name will be considered in the patent if it is granted ?

Comment: What does your employment contract say regarding IP you help develop and patents?

Comment: It says they are would be part of the company. Even if they are part of the all patents have name of the author and co-author. I am wondering whether my name would be there in the patent or not.

Comment: There likely isn't a law.  You need to check company policy or check your contract or ask your manager.  This might be a better fit on workplace.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a law (35 U.S.C. 115 ). In the U.S., the actual true inventors are the actual true inventors and must be named as the inventors. Look to your employee agreement and state law to understand the issues of ownership.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. I contributed to an invention near the end of the 20th century and then left the company. The company applied for a patent in the early 21st century; I was asked to sign the application. The patent was eventually granted. My name appears in the patent as an inventor.